# How do I get the correct size of a char*?

Tags: c++

New to C++, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

I have a char[], containing an AES key (the key here is for demo only):

```
char oldkey[] = {0x7c, 0x4f, 0xd7, 0xc2, 0xfb, 0x09, 0x1f, 0xef, 0x6d, 0x34, 0x1a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0xd7, 0xb5, 0x17};
```

I'm moving from storing the key in this format to storing a base64 encoded string, which is decoded using CryptStringToBinary:

```
int DecodeBase64( const BYTE * src, unsigned int srcLen, char * dst, unsigned int dstLen ) {
    DWORD outLen;
    BOOL fRet;
    outLen = dstLen;
    fRet = CryptStringToBinary( (LPCSTR) src, srcLen, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, (BYTE * )dst, &outLen, NULL, NULL);
    
    if (!fRet) outLen = 0;  // failed
    return( outLen );
}
  
void * key_mem;
unsigned char key[] = "fE/XwvsJH+9tNBp4bde1Fw=="; //base64 of old_key
unsigned int key_len = sizeof(key);
key_mem = VirtualAlloc(0, key_len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

DecodeBase64((const BYTE *) key, key_len, (char *) key_mem, key_len);

char* decoded_key = (char*)key_mem;
```

Calling sizeof on decoded_key and oldkey gives two different results:

```
printf("\n%i\n", sizeof(decoded_key)); //8
printf("\n%i\n", sizeof(oldkey)); //16
```

The data in decoded_key is correct. It works with my AES algorithm, if I pass the correct key length. How can I get the correct length of decoded_key (16)?

Comment: `oldkey` is an array and `decoded_key` is a pointer, that's why you get the different results.

Comment: How you get the correct length does rather depend on what you mean by length.

Comment: `sizeof(oldKey)` gives you the size in bytes of the oldkey array. Each char is 1 byte on your compiler, you have 16 chars in your array => size is 16
`sizeof(decodedKey)` gives you the size of a pointer to char

I'm not sure what exaclty you mean by length and what you get, but the results you're getting are 'correct' as far as they return exactly what you stated in the code as needing.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to get the size of the data in decodedKey, rather than the size of the pointer? Apologies if the code isn't clear. I need to get the actual size of the key (16 bytes).

Comment: @Jay In general no there isn't. But looking at your code it appear that the `outLen` variable returned from `DecodeBase64` is the value you want.

Comment: @john you're absolutely correct, not sure how I missed that. thanks!

Comment: @Jay However your code seems to have a few errors (mostly caused my misunderstandings of how to get the size of things) so I suspect that the call to `CryptStringToBinary` to going to fail and you're going to get a zero return value.

Comment: @Jay This would help `unsigned int key_len = strlen((const char*)key);`. `strlen` is the way to get the length of a null terminated string (which is what `key` is).

Comment: @john that's great, thanks for the help

Comment: `oldkey` should be `unsigned char` in the first place as it represents a byte array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecodeBase64` returns a value.

```
int DecodeBase64(....  // <------------------------------- this int right here
{
     return( outLen ); // <------------------------------- this variable right here
}
```

That's the length you need. Use it.

```
int decodedLen = DecodeBase64((const BYTE *) key, key_len, (char *) key_mem, key_len);
////////////// this one
```

You cannot use `sizeof` because the decoded key doesn't have to occupy the entire buffer. You cannot use `strlen` because the decoded key is not a string. That's why `DecodeBase64` returns a value. You cannot ignore it because there is no other way to get the size.

Answer (score 1):

Because your decoded_key type is pointer, so it will have a constant size depends on your architecture (commonly 4 or 8 bytes).
In C/C++, giving the only pointer, there is no way to get the correct size of data which is pointed by that pointer, you have to track it by additional variable yourself.

In this case, to guess the correct size, you should read the document of VirtualAlloc():

LPVOID VirtualAlloc(
LPVOID lpAddress,
SIZE_T dwSize,
DWORD  flAllocationType,
DWORD  flProtect
);

dwSize parameter: (for your case that is the key_len).
The size of the region, in bytes. If the lpAddress parameter is NULL, this value is rounded up to the next page boundary. Otherwise, the allocated pages include all pages containing one or more bytes in the range from lpAddress to lpAddress+dwSize. This means that a 2-byte range straddling a page boundary causes both pages to be included in the allocated region.

Depend on the condition, you can calculate the size as the document mentioned.